# Working example of MongoDB Scala query filter using "_id" (Mongo document's ObjectID) with value?

Tags: mongodb, scala

Referencing this [MongoDB Scala Driver 2.9 documentation on the topic of Filters](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/2.9/builders/filters/), I am not able to find a working example that allows me to query by `_id`, Mongo's document id.

http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/2.9/builders/filters/

My first unsuccessful naive attempt does not work.  Because I redacted the `_id` value.
The actual `_id` exists in my collection when I used Studio 3T application.

```scala
collection.find(equal("_id", "ABC1234567890")).subscribe((doc: Document) => println(doc.toJson()))
```

I have also tried to read through the ScalaDocs available [here](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/2.9/scaladoc/org/mongodb/scala/model/Filters$.html), but the function descriptions do not contain any working examples neither.

My second naive attempt does not work either.

```scala
val exQ1 = BsonDocument("_id" -> BsonDocument("$eq" -> "ABC1234567890"))
collection.find(exQ1).subscribe((doc: Document) => println(doc.toJson()))
```

Any assistance in debunking this or references that can help are appreciated.

**Updated** (2022-04-28):

Based on Luis comment suggestion for trying out `ObjectId` class, here is what happened.

1. Searched `ObjectId` via [Mongo Scala driver v2.9](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/2.9/scaladoc/index.html), only [org.mongodb.scala.bson.BsonObjectId class](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/2.9/scaladoc/org/mongodb/scala/bson/BsonObjectId$.html) exists.
2. Used `BsonObjectId` for the query construction as follows:

```scala
val exQ2 = BsonDocument("_id" -> BsonObjectId("$eq" -> "ABC1234567890"))
```

Got the following error:

```scala
error: overloaded method value apply with alternatives:
  (value: org.mongodb.scala.bson.ObjectId)org.mongodb.scala.bson.BsonObjectId <and>
  (value: String)org.mongodb.scala.bson.BsonObjectId
 cannot be applied to ((String, String))
val exQ2 = BsonDocument("_id" -> BsonObjectId("$eq" -> "ABC1234567890"))
                                 ^
```

3. Refactored the query as follows satisfied the parameter type:

```scala
val exQ2 = BsonDocument("_id" -> BsonObjectId("ABC1234567890"))
```

But now I get the following:

```scala
IllegalArgumentException: invalid hexadecimal representation of an ObjectId: [ABC1234567890]
```

I used the actual string value (instead of this dummy fake value) of the `_id` the error message is still the same.

I am investigating the need to convert the literal string of the document id to a hexadecimal representation to make this work as the next step.

Comment: `"ABC1234567890"` is not a valid **Mongo** id, you probably want `ObjectId("ABC1234567890")` but still does not follow the official format, it may be best to use a different field.

Comment: I redacted the real Mongo ID value with a fake one.  I stated that to make sure it doesn't confuse people.  Thank you for highlighting it.    I will try the ObjectId approach and see what happens.